# Using extension methods from within the class they extend

Tags: c#, class, extension-methods

Consider this class:

```
public class Thing {

    public string Color { get; set; }

    public bool IsBlue() {
        return this.Color == "Blue";   // redundant "this"
    }

}
```

I can omit the keyword `this` because `Color` is a property of `Thing`, and I'm coding within `Thing`.

If I now create an extension method:

```
public static class ThingExtensions {

    public static bool TestForBlue(this Thing t) {
        return t.Color == "Blue";
    }

}
```

I can now change my `IsBlue` method to this:

```
public class Thing {

    public string Color { get; set; }

    public bool IsBlue() {
        return this.TestForBlue();   // "this" is now required
    }
}
```

However, I'm now required to include the `this` keyword.

I can omit `this` when referencing properties and methods, so why can't I do this...?

```
public bool IsBlue() {
    return TestForBlue();
}
```

Comment: Extension methods don't actually extend a type. They only appear to thanks to IDE and compiler tricks.

Comment: btw, I can easily type `this`, I'm just OCD about coding neatness, and the keyword annoys me!!!

Comment: The question referred to by Habib answers this perfectly

Comment: Damn... I did try to search for dup questions first... but couldn't find anything!! obviously didn't look hard enough.

Comment: It can also be called like a normal static method `ThingExtensions.TestForBlue(this)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I can omit this when referencing properties and methods, so why can't I do this...?

It's just part of how extension methods are invoked, basically. Section 7.6.5.2 of the C# specification (Extension Method Invocations) starts:

> In a method invocation (7.5.5.1) of one of the forms
>
> *expr* . *identifier* `(` `)`
> *expr* . *identifier* `(` *args* `)`
> *expr* . *identifier* `<` *typeargs* `>` `(` `)`
> *expr* . *identifier* `<` *typeargs* `>` `(` *args* `)`
>
> if the normal processing of the invocation finds no applicable methods, an attempt is made to process the construct as an extension method invocation.

Without the `this`, your invocation wouldn't be of that form, so that section of the spec wouldn't apply.

This isn't a justification of why the feature was *designed* that way, of course - it's a justification of the compiler's behaviour in terms of correctness.

Comment: From which document does Section 7.6.5.2 refer? Google doesn't seem to know...

Comment: @BG100 The C# 5.0 language specifications.

Comment: @BG100: The specification is free at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029 .

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to invoke which ***extension method type*** is it gonna call, since the Extension is defined as **Thing**, the **object** needs to call itself and the **static method** that was defined for it.

Comment: The C# specs could have easily checked the calling class (and base classes) and checked for us. They just didn't. I can only assume at some point they will add this in for us.